# does spring provide 2 mvc platforms, grails and spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, grails

Just reading spring in action, and I know there is a chapter on MVC that I havent' got to yet.

I also read about grails, is that another framework or built on top of spring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Grails is built on Spring (and several other frameworks) and it uses Spring MVC to implement its MVC layer.